# Dependencies of the package in pip repos

Tags: python, pip

How can one command find out all dependencies of the package and links to dependent packages in the repository pip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `johnnydep`

```
pip install johnnydep
```

Example: `johnnydep ipython`

```
ipython                           IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
├── appnope                       Disable App Nap on OS X 10.9
├── backcall                      Specifications for callback functions passed in to an API
├── decorator                     Better living through Python with decorators
├── jedi>=0.10                    An autocompletion tool for Python that can be used for text editors.
│   └── parso>=0.3.0              A Python Parser
├── pexpect                       Pexpect allows easy control of interactive console applications.
│   └── ptyprocess>=0.5           Run a subprocess in a pseudo terminal
├── pickleshare                   Tiny 'shelve'-like database with concurrency support
├── prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0  Library for building powerful interactive command lines in Python
│   ├── six>=1.9.0                Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
│   └── wcwidth                   Measures number of Terminal column cells of wide-character codes
├── pygments                      Pygments is a syntax highlighting package written in Python.
├── setuptools>=18.5              Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
├── simplegeneric>0.8             Simple generic functions (similar to Python's own len(), pickle.dump(), etc.)
└── traitlets>=4.2                Traitlets Python config system
    ├── decorator                 Better living through Python with decorators
    ├── ipython-genutils          Vestigial utilities from IPython
    └── six                       Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
```

You can also display download links to dependant packages by adding the `--fields download_link` option:

```
 johnnydep ipython --fields download_link
```

.

```
name                              download_link
--------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipython                           https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/27/29d66ed395a5c2c3a912332d446a54e2bc3277c36b0bbd22bc71623e0193/ipython-7.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
├── appnope                       https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/a9/7985e6a53402f294c8f0e8eff3151a83f1fb901fa92909bb3ff29b4d22af/appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── backcall                      https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/71/c8ca4f5bb1e08401b916c68003acf0a0655df935d74d93bf3f3364b310e0/backcall-0.1.0.tar.gz
├── decorator                     https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── jedi>=0.10                    https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/1a/9bd24a185873b998611c2d8d4fb15cd5e8a879ead36355df7ee53e9111bf/jedi-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
│   └── parso>=0.3.0              https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/51/9c48a46334be50c13d25a3afe55fa05c445699304c5ad32619de953a2305/parso-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── pexpect                       https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e6/b5a1de8b0cc4e07ca1b305a4fcc3f9806025c1b651ea302646341222f88b/pexpect-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
│   └── ptyprocess>=0.5           https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── pickleshare                   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/41/220f49aaea88bc6fa6cba8d05ecf24676326156c23b991e80b3f2fc24c77/pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/c5/f1ee6698bdcf615f171a77e81ca70293b16a6d82285f1760b388b4348263/prompt_toolkit-2.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
│   ├── six>=1.9.0                https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
│   └── wcwidth                   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── pygments                      https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/ee/b6e02dc6529e82b75bb06823ff7d005b141037cb1416b10c6f00fc419dca/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── setuptools>=18.5              https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/06/c8ee69628191285ddddffb277bd5abdf769166e7a14b867c2a172f0175b1/setuptools-40.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── simplegeneric>0.8             https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/57/4d9c9e3ae9a255cd4e1106bb57e24056d3d0709fc01b2e3e345898e49d5b/simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
└── traitlets>=4.2                https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    ├── decorator                 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    ├── ipython-genutils          https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    └── six                       https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```